# Double click a cell in a table and filter another table based on R1C2

Tags: excel, vba, double-click, excel-r1c1-notation

I'm trying to create a small table that you can double click on any cell and filter a second table based on the values in row 1 (AYEAR) and column B (AMONTH) to return the breakdown of the total value from my original table. How do I express this using R1C1 reference style?

```
ACLICK = Activecell.Address
AMONTH = RC2.Value
AYEAR = R1C.Value
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It needs to always look at row 1 for AYEAR and column B for AMONTH no matter which cell I'm double clicking in... EG: If I double click in J9 it needs to look at J1 for AYEAR and B9 for AMONTH

Simply:

```
AMONTH = Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Value ' or Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "B")
AYEAR = Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column).Value
```

---

**Original answer**:

IIUC, you're looking for [`Offset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset), and there's no need to use `.Address` or even think about R1C1 notation.

```
AMONTH = ActiveCell.Offset(,1).Value
AYEAR = ActiveCell.Offeset(1).Value
```

Comment: It needs to always look at row 1 for AYEAR and column B for AMONTH no matter which cell I'm double clicking in. I see what you've done and that's very helpful for future use. EG: If I double click in J9 it needs to look at J1 for AYEAR and B9 for AMONTH.

Comment: @Frinkenstein - oh ok, see the edit.

Comment: Legend, worked like a charm! My fault for not explaining myself properly. Thank you sir.